# What is the penalty, if any, for mistakenly paying US federal taxes as US tax resident instead of a non-US tax resident?

Tags: united-states, taxes, penalty, tax-residency

[Determining the US tax residency](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/1/183-day-rule.asp) can be slightly [tricky](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/124871/5656) and as a result I wonder what the penalty is, if any, for mistakenly paying US federal taxes as US tax resident instead of a non-US tax resident.

Assume that paying US federal taxes as US tax resident doesn't yield any money saving compared to filing as a non-US tax resident (i.e., no malicious intent, just an genuine mistake).

Answer (score 2):

If no additional tax is due, likely there is [no penalty](https://davidgreeneattorney.com/what-happens-if-i-have-made-a-mistake-on-my-tax-return/). You can file to amend your mistaken return with Form 1040-X.